# Event does not fire more than once

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, events

In my angular app i am trying to upload a file. I am having problem with firing the event every time i select the file. I am able to fire the event for first time but it does not work next time. How can i resolve it. please guide me.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <label class="file-label" for="file-upload">Please upload your data. click here!
              <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="file-upload" accept=".zip" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" [hidden]="true">
          </div>
```

TS

```
onFileSelected(event) {
console.log(event.target.files);
}
```

Comment: Do you try to select same file? Browser caches selected file and if next file has same name it will not fire the event.

Comment: I am selecting the same file. How can i clean my cache or what can i do to overcome it.

Comment: call method on click instead of onFileSelected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting a file you should clean input value `event.target.value = ''`.